# Retrieve tweets in ascending order with a defined timeframe

Tags: python, twitter

Currently, I am working on creating datasets by using Twitter API. I have some question that you might be able to help me out. For example, the first dataset that I have to create is related to the early hashtag adopters, I mean, by using a specific hashtag as the search word in a certain timeframe, I will retrieve the first 50 users ID who have used the hashtag on their tweets.

The problem I'm facing is that it will show me the most recent tweets that match the query, but what I want is the other way round, I mean, in ascending order. So, I am wondering if this is possible to do it.

PD: I am using `searchtweets` package in python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, there isn't a way to make premium api return things in chronological order (it will always return newest first).